# where am I find the Listeners for view detach/attach

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to know how to detecte the listener when I do click in the "Detached option" of the menu popup of a view eclipse rcp.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain, what you want to do with it?

I would try the following:
Use the plug-in spy (requires Eclipse Galileo), press alt+shift+F2,
Now you find the class org.eclipse.ui.internal.DetachedWindow and its
plugin org.eclipse.ui.workbench.
Next, [debug eclipse with itself](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg62815.html). You should be able
to backtrace to the listener.